# Supply either STDIN or a file pathname option to Python Click CLI script

Tags: python, python-click

I'm trying out Click for the first time but I've hit a stumbling block.

I want my (two) subcommands to either take a file pathname option *or* accept file contents from STDIN.

- Allowed: Use a path for --compose-file

  ```sh
  ./docker-secret-helper.py secret-hash-ini --compose-file docker-compose-test.yml
  ```
- Allowed: Use contents of a file as stdin

  ```sh
  cat docker-compose-test.yml | ./docker-secret-helper.py secret-hash-ini
  ```

  (Should there be an option to indicate stdin, e.g., `-i`, or whatever?)
- Not Allowed: Neither --compose-file nor stdin passed

  ```sh
  ./docker-secret-helper.py secret-hash-ini
  ```

  Should return something like: `You must either pass --compose-file or pipe in stdin.`

Current Script

My current script accepts (only) the file pathname (via `--compose-file`):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import click
from DockerSecretHelper import DockerSecretHelper

CONTEXT_SETTINGS = dict(help_option_names=['-h', '--help'])

@click.group(context_settings=CONTEXT_SETTINGS)
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command(help="retrieves an ini-style file of variables to be used as env vars for docker-compose commmand")
@click.option('--compose-file', help='compose file to work with', required=True)
def secret_hash_ini(**kwargs):
    helper = DockerSecretHelper()
    print(helper.get_secret_hash_ini_format_from_compose_file(**kwargs))
    # will need some kind of if block to call helper.get_secret_hash_ini_format_from_compose_contents(**kwargs) in the
    #  case of stdin

@cli.command(help="retrieves names/values of external secrets; to be used by `docker secret set`")
@click.option('--compose-file', help='compose file to work with', required=True)
def external_secret_info_json(**kwargs):
    helper = DockerSecretHelper()
    print(helper.get_external_secret_info_as_json_from_compost_file(**kwargs))
    # will need some kind of if block to call helper.get_external_secret_info_as_json_from_compose_contents(**kwargs) in
    # the case of stdin

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

How do I implement and enforce either STDIN *or* a file pathname (but not both).

I'm open to changes to my command's syntax to better follow potential conventions.

This question is similar to [Creating command line application in python using Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193589/creating-command-line-application-in-python-using-click) so it might provide some building blocks (which I'm having trouble assembling).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use click's `File` option type:

```
import click
import sys


@click.group()
def cli():
    pass


@cli.command()
@click.option('--compose-file', 
              help='compose file to work with',
              type=click.File('r'),
              default=sys.stdin)
def secret_hash_ini(compose_file):
    with compose_file:
        data = compose_file.read()

    print(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Assuming we have a file `example.txt` that contains the text:

```
This is a test.
```

Then we can specify a file with `--compose-file`:

```
$ python docker-secret-helper.py secret-hash-ini --compose-file example.txt
This is a test.
```

Or we can read from `stdin`:

```
$ python docker-secret-helper.py secret-hash-ini < example.txt
This is a test.
```

We can't generate an error in the case that "Neither --compose-file nor stdin passed" because `stdin` is always available.  If we call `docker-secret-helper.py` without providing `--compose-file` and without redirecting `stdin`, it will simply hang waiting for input.

Comment: You can prevent the hang with: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.isatty  This can be used to insure stdin is a pipe...

Answer (score 2):

To make this more universal, you can also do the same thing for output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Example to read from stdin and write to stdout when no filenames are given.
"""
import sys
from string import Template
import click

@click.command()
@click.option(
    "--file",
    help="Filename of the template, omit to read from STDIN.",
    type=click.File("rt"),
    default=sys.stdin,
)
@click.option(
    "--out",
    help="File to write the Output to, omit to display on screen.",
    type=click.File("at"),
    default=sys.stdout,
)
def generate(file, out):
    """Read the file, and write to out."""
    template = Template(file.read())
    click.echo("#Write something", file=out)
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    generate()
```

so you can do `./my_sript.py < some.tpl > output.txt` as well as `./my_script.py --file=some.tpl --out=output.txt`